# How to do JOIN with comparison of several fields and NOT IN of other field

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

[image]

I would like to join the both tables based on the condition of column A, B, and C match between two tables, but the column D in Table A does not exist in Table B, provided the column A, B and C match.

So something like this:

```
 SELECT A.*
 FROM   tableA A
 JOIN   tableB B ON A.A = B.A AND A.B = B.B AND A.C = B.C
 -- but 
 A.D NOT IN B.D, where the 3 conditions above match
```

The expected result is

Table A:

```
 1 | 3 | 4 | 7
 1 | 4 | 5 | 8
```

Is it possible to do in one query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM  tableA A 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tableB B 
              WHERE A.A = B.A AND A.B = B.B AND A.C = B.C
             ) AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tableB B 
                  WHERE A.D = B.D
                 );
```

Of course, you can use `JOIN` for the first comparison.  But since you only want columns for `A~ that doesn't seem necessarily.

EDIT:

It is a little unclear what exactly you want, but you seem to want:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM  tableA A 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tableB B 
              WHERE A.A = B.A AND A.B = B.B AND A.C = B.C AND A.D <> B.D
             ) AND
```

Comment: This does not seem correct. only get the first row but not the second row

Comment: @rcs . . . On the sample data in your question, it should return both the first two rows.  Can you set up a db fiddle with sample data?

Comment: I've setup here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4S9Fy5x253DtvAYqsnttfj/0

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want

```
SELECT A.*
 FROM   tableA A
 JOIN   tableB B
    ON A.A = B.A 
     AND A.B = B.B
     AND A.C = B.C
     AND B.D <> A.D
```

Based on your expected results, it seems you simply want a match across A|B|C, but not a match across A|B|C|D

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT A.*
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN tableB B ON A.A = B.A AND A.B = B.B AND A.C = B.C AND A.D = B.D
WHERE 
    B.D IS NULL
```